# Event Driven MessageBus architecture with AWS SNS: one or many message buses/ lambda action functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

I am implementing a process in my AWS based hosting business with an event driven architecture on AWS SNS. This is largely a learning experience with a new architecture, programming and hosting paradigm for me.

I have considered AWS Step functions, but have decided to implement a Message Bus with AWS SNS topic(s), because I want to understand the underlying event driven programming model.

Nearly all actions are performed by lambda functions and steps are coupled via SNS and/or SQS.

I am undecided if to implement the process with one or many SNS topics and if I should subscribe the core logic to the message bus(es) with one or many lambda functions.

**One or many message buses**

My core process currently consist of 9 events which of which 2 sets of 2 can be parallel, the remaining 4 are sequential. Subscribing these all to the same message bus is easier to set up, but requires each lambda function to check if the message is relevant to it, which seems like a waste of resources.

On the other hand I could have 6 message buses and be sure that a notified resource has something to do with the message.

**One or many lambda functions**

If all lambda functions are subscribed to the same message bus, it may be easier to package them all up with a dispatcher function in a single lambda function. It would also reduce the amount of code to upload to lambda, albeit I don't have to pay for that.

On the other hand I would loose the ability to control the timeout for the lambda function and any changes to the order of events is now dependent on the dispatcher code.

I would still have the ability to scale each process part, as any parts that contain repeating elements are seperated by SQS queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always emit each type of message to it's own topic, as this allows other services to consume these events without tightly coupling the two services.

Likewise, each worker that wants to consume messages should have it's own queue with it's own subscription to the topic.

Doing the following allows you to add new message consumers for a given event without having to modify the upstream service. Furthermore, responsibility over each component is clear - the service producing messages to a topic owns that topic (and the message format), whereas the consumer owns its queue and event handling semantics.

Your consumer can specify a message filter when subscribing to a topic, so it can only receive messages it cares about ([documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-filtering.html)).

For example, a process that sends a customer survey after the customer has received their order would subscribe its queue to the `Order Status Changed` event with the filter set to only receive events where the `new_status` field is equal to `shipment-received`).

The above reflects principles of Service-Oriented architecture - and there's plenty of good material out there elaborating the points above.

Comment: Going back to your original statement, it's also worth noting that AWS has another (more fully featured) orchestration service named Amazon Simple Workflow Service (SWF).

I'd suggest there's still value in this in the case your higher level process has branching or conditional logic in it - but keeping that separate from  your messaging-based services will add some overhead.